# Planting Seeds in the Winter in Georgia (USA)

Tags: grass

I've recently used a tractor to change the slope of my yard in order to cause water to flow away from the house during heavy rains. This has caused basically all vegetation to be scraped off my yard. Does anyone know what type of grass is best for me to plant now in this season that will germinate quickly? I've researched and determined that rye grass may be viable, but it can be invasive and may only be green during cooler seasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get some annual rye grass.  Annual is the key word.  Get it planted, lightly covered, add some high nitrogen fertilizer and do it now.  If it is too cold oh well.  Georgia, this stuff should grow.  It is used as a cover crop in gardens. My favorite cover crop.

As an annual it needs to be turned under in the spring before allowing it to go to seed.  Otherwise you have nothing to worry about.

Another option would be to contact a grass company that sprays seed and mulch and fertilizer and boy does this work.  Worth the money. Not expensive at all. They will know exactly what it is you need now.

You might even have to get some rolls of netted hemp. It is like burlap only thicker and looser. Secured with big staples this will protect your soil from erosion.  Like immediately.